# Regular expression to match one or more patterns matching another regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

I am using regular expressions for my [django url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) configurations. I have the following regex:

```
url(r'^myapp/prices/?([X]{1}[A-Z0-9]{3}:[A-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z09.-]{1,4})/?([0-9]{0,3})/?$', views.prices, name='prices'),
```

This matches urls such as:

- htpp://127.0.0.1/myapp/prices/XNAS:GOOG/1
- htpp://127.0.0.1/myapp/prices/XNAS:GOOG
- htpp://127.0.0.1/myapp/prices/XNAS:FB/10

I want to modify my regex pattern in my url pattern, so that I can match on strings like the above, **as well as** strings like the one  below:

> htpp://127.0.0.1/myapp/prices/XNAS:GOOG+XNAS:TSLA+XNAS:FB/1

Essentially, I want my original pattern to be matched at least once, and if more than once, then the occurrences of the pattern should be separated by a '+' sign.

How would I express this using regex syntax (Python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
repeatable = r'[X]{1}[A-Z0-9]{3}:[A-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z09.-]{1,4}'
url_regex = r'^myapp/prices/?(' + re.escape(repeatable) + r')(\+' + re.escape(repeatable) + r')*/?([0-9]{0,3})/?$'

url(url_regex, views.prices, name='prices')
```

But I believe it's more complicated that this:

```
url(r'^myapp/prices/?([X]{1}[A-Z0-9]{3}:[A-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z09.-]{1,4})(\+?[X]{1}[A-Z0-9]{3}:[A-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z09.-]{1,4})*/?([0-9]{0,3})/?$', views.prices, name='prices'),
```

Comment: this just allows for an option '+' character, I want to be able to have the original pattern repeated an "infinite" number of times. I think you have set me on the righ path though, let me try to modify your regex ...

Comment: Yes, that looks like it should work - but IIRC, there is a way in regex, where groups can be 'named' to avoid having to repeat the same patterns over again, and keep the expression more legible - are you aware of how to use that syntax? the expression is looking quite unwieldy (scary!)

Comment: It remains scary even though variables are used. Choose what fits your (optical) needs!

Comment: I'm still trying to get the "less complicated" :) one you posted earlier, to work. At the moment, it only matches the first and last tickers. For example, if I call `/prices/XNYS:F+XNYS:IBM+XNAS:GOOG` the called function only sees **XNYS:F** and **XNAS:GOOG** but when I used the new url pattern you supplied,  I had to modify the called view method  it complained that it expected 3 args and had been passed 4 args instead.

Comment: Inside the regex you have `....:[A-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z09.-]{1,4}` which means after the `:` it should match 1 characters and after that 1 to 4 characters BUT in `/prices/XNYS:F+XNYS:IBM+XNAS:GOOG` after `:` you pass `F` which is OK but after that nothing! If you want it to work this should be rewritten to `....:[A-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z09.-]{0,4}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138483/discussion-between-homunculus-reticulli-and-nik-m).